# Remover texto dentro de uma tag comentário com PHP?

Tags: php

O meu cliente costuma fazer *copy*/*paste* de fornecedores de notícias que contêm comentários HTML.

Ou seja, no HTML não faz mal e ao inserir eles não aparecem no editor de texto mas porém eu uso o `PHP mailer` que acaba por enviar esse texto e deixa visível esses comentários.

Indico abaixo um exemplo:

`<!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4; mso-font-charset:1; mso-generic-font-family:roman; mso-font-format:other; mso-font-pitch:variable; mso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;} @font-face {font-... -->`

O que posso fazer para que, antes de inserir na base de dados, ele remova esta tag?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: @MagicHat Mas como é que defino aquela tag? `echo strip_tags($text, '<!-- -->');` Assim?

Comment: Sei lá mano, foi só uma sugestão, faz uns testes... Achei que essa função serviria,olha o nome dela... Qui a pouco aparece alguém com preg_match, também....

Comment: O `strip_tags($texto)` vai remover todas as tags de HTML e vai deixar só o texto no lugar. Se quiser deixar alguma tag para trás use a forma `strip_tags($texto,"[<tag>]+")` onde `[<tag>]+` significa a transcrição literal uma ou mais tags que queira deixar passar. Agora se precisar fazer uma busca do texto e apagar o que estiver com tag a resposta do @Sam é o se deve fazer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por que não usa um [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)?

```
<?
$string = 'a<!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4; mso-font-charset:1;
 mso-generic-font-family:roman; mso-font-format:other; mso-font-pitch:variable; mso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;} @font-face {font-
 ... -->b<!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4; mso-font-charset:1;
  mso-generic-font-family:roman; mso-font-format:other; mso-font-pitch:variable; mso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;} @font-face {font-... -->';
$string = preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/s', '', $string);
echo $string; // imprime: ab
?>
```

O padrão da expressão regular `/<!--.*?-->/s` irá buscar tudo que estiver entre os sinais `<!--` e `-->` (inclusive os sinais) e remover da string.

Note no exemplo acima que só existe uma letra "a" e um "b" fora dos blocos de comentário. Logo, ao fazer o replace, só restarão essas duas letras na string.

**[Teste no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/jDuBZD)**

Comment: Usei o seu método mas por alguma razão. Isolei o comentário do html e ele eliminou mas ao usar o texto todo ele deixa de funcionar.

Comment: Eu fiz uma alteração recente na regex: `/<!--.*?-->/s`... veja se vc colocou exatamente dessa forma.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme já comentado, uma opção é usar [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), pois ela removerá os comentários HTML da string:

```
$string = '<p>texto</p><!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4; mso-font-charset:1;
 mso-generic-font-family:roman; mso-font-format:other; mso-font-pitch:variable; mso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;} @font-face {font-
 ... --><span>Mais texto</span><!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4; mso-font-charset:1;
  mso-generic-font-family:roman; mso-font-format:other; mso-font-pitch:variable; mso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;} @font-face {font-... -->';
echo strip_tags($string);
```

O detalhe é que esta função remove todas as tags HTML, deixando somente o texto:

```
textoMais texto
```

Mas você pode passar uma lista das tags que devem ser mantidas. Por exemplo:

```
// manter as tags <p> e <span>
echo strip_tags($string, "<p><span>");
```

Saída:

```
<p>texto</p><span>Mais texto</span>
```

---

Mas se a sua string tiver muitas tags HTML, pode ser meio tedioso passar a lista de todas as tags válidas para `strip_tags`. Então outra opção é usar [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// remover os comentários
foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment) {
    $comment->parentNode->removeChild($comment);
}

// obter o body do documento (agora sem comentários) como uma string
$newString = "";
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$children  = $body->childNodes;
foreach ($children as $child) { 
    $newString .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
echo $newString;
```

Saída:

```
<p>texto</p>
<span>Mais texto</span>
```

---

#### Regex

Se quer mesmo usar regex, pode usar:

```
echo preg_replace('/<!--[^>]*-->/', '', $string);
```

Diferenças com relação à [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383029/112052) (que também está correta):

O `.*?` indica que a regex vai pegar zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere. Graças à opção `s` usada na outra resposta, o ponto corresponde inclusive a quebras de linha (por *default* ele não tem esse comportamento), e o `?` indica que a regex tenta pegar o mínimo possível de caracteres (isso evita que o ponto acabe pegando um fechamento de comentários "sem querer", já que o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, e se a regex achar necessário, ela pode pegar `-->`).

Já eu usei `[^>]*`: zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere que **não** seja `>`. Isso faz com que a regex seja um pouquinho mais rápida (já que `.*?`, apesar de ser muito conveniente e funcionar, [tem o seu preço](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazytrap): como o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, a regex precisa ficar indo e voltando várias vezes na string verificando e testando se precisa consumir mais caracteres que a satisfaçam). Veja que a [versão com `.*?`](https://regex101.com/r/U5nK7l/1/debugger) precisa de 9 a 10 vezes mais passos para executar do que [a versão com `[^>]*`](https://regex101.com/r/BBtSqc/1/debugger).

Obviamente, para poucas execuções e strings pequenas, a diferença será irrelevante (talvez só faça diferença para processamentos muito extensos e strings bem grandes). E mesmo a quantidade de passos pode variar, já que cada linguagem e *engine* possui otimizações internas distintas (mas em geral, [dizer exatamente o que você quer - e o que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) - *geralmente* faz a regex ser mais rápida do que usar `.*`).

---

**Só há um porém**: se dentro dos comentários tiver um `>` (mas que não seja o fechamento do comentário), a regex acima não funciona ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/BBtSqc/2/)). Nesse caso, pode continuar usando `.*?` mesmo ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/U5nK7l/2/)). Ou, se quiser usar algo realmente complicado:

```
$string = '<p>texto</p><!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4; mso-font-charset:1; mso-generic-font-family:roman; mso-font-format:other; mso-font-pitch:variable;> ESSE CARACTERE AQUI QUEBRA TUDOmso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;} @font-face {font- ... --><span>Mais texto</span><!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4; mso-font-charset:1;  mso-generic-font-family:roman; mso-font-format:other; mso-font-pitch:variable; mso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;} @font-face {font-... -->';
echo preg_replace('/<!--(?>[^-]*)(?>(?!-->)-[^-]*)*-->/', '', $string);
```

Esta regex usa a técnica de [*unroll the loop*](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) (retirada [deste livro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)), e usa vários recursos avançados para detectar um comentário (como [grupos atômicos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) - os trechos com `(?>` - para evitar o *backtracking* - o "vai e vem" para verificar os vários trechos da regex, que nem sempre são necessários). Ela resolve o problema do `>` mencionado acima, e apesar de mais complicada, ainda sim ela é mais rápida do que usar `.*?` - compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/U5nK7l/2/debugger) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/BBtSqc/4/debugger)). Ela também elimina os comentários e a saída é:

```
<p>texto</p><span>Mais texto</span>
```

---

Embora regex seja legal (eu particularmente gosto muito), eu acho a solução com `DOMDocument` mais simples (já que é uma biblioteca específica para lidar com todas as particularidades da sintaxe HTML - algo que, como você pode ver, não é tão trivial com regex).

Uma regex pode até lidar com casos mais simples, mas [complique um pouco mais seu HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013499) e o problema passa a ser mais difícil do que parecia (obviamente que, se suas strings não caem nesses casos mais complexos, usar `.*?` ou qualquer outra das expressões sugeridas acima funciona sem problemas).