# Regex - definir 2 limites e pegar todo conteúdo dentro

Tags: string, regex

Na string abaixo, preciso pegar o conteúdo de texto a partir de `ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO` até o símbolo do percentual `%`. Ou seja:

```
ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO kWh 370 0,787324 291,31 291,31 29,00%
```

É possível fazer isso por meio de regex? Não encontrei nenhum tutorial que explique como definir 2 limites e pegar todo o conteúdo entre eles.

```
"5758 6128 370 kWh 1 370 kWh 11,93 kWh 12/07/2019 01/08/2019
Mês kWh Dt.Pgto. Valor
06/2019 355 17/06/2019 343,79
NOTA FISCAL/CONTA DE ENERGIA ELÉTRICA N° 085.976.711 - SÉRIE B
Emitida em 03/07/2019
05/2019 332 14/05/2019 306,84
Produto Valor Valor Base Aliq.
04/2019 415 29/05/2019 378,67
Descrição Un. Consumo Unitário Total Cálc. ICMS
03/2019 308 14/05/2019 269,81
ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO kWh 370 0,787324 291,31 291,31 29,00%
02/2019 347 26/04/2019 305,09
ENERGIA CONS. B.AMARELA kWh 0,54 0,54 29,00%
01/2019 341 11/03/2019 324,39
12/2018 301 26/12/2018 287,83"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considerando que o delimitador terminal só pode aparecer uma única vez, e que ele é de apenas um caracter no seu exemplo é o `%`), fiz um pequeno ajuste na [resposta do nullptr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400433/64969) para tal fim:

```
ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO[^%]*%
```

Agora, em termos gerais:

Para qualquer sequência iniciadora `INIT`, podendo ela ser repetida na sequência, e um terminador `@` de um caracter que não pode estar contido exceto no final da sequência:

```
INIT[^@]*@
```

Para um iniciador qualquer de um caracter `£` que não pode ser repetido dentro e um terminador de um caracter que também não pode ser repetido:

```
£[^£@]*@
```

Se for plausível aceitar um caracter de escape (fingindo ser o `#`), em que o escape pode se escapar também, e que o iniciador `£` ou o terminador `@` podem ser escapados no meio da sequência (não podendo aparecer livres):

```
£([^#£@]|#.)*@
```

Aqui, vale uma explicação:

- começa com `£`, como esperado de um iniciador
- termina com um `@`, como esperado de um terminador
- pode conter um grupo com diversas repetições de `g1` ou `g2`
- `g1` é qualquer caracter que não seja escape, iniciador ou terminador
- `g2` é o escape seguido de qualquer coisa, incluindo (mas não limitado a): iniciador, escape e terminador

Como consequência da montagem de `g1`, um escape só poderá aparecer em elemento de `g2`. E `g2` começa garantidamente com um escape e tem um outro caracter; logo, não há escapes faltando, eles estão sempre seguidos de algo.

---

Se por acaso a sequência que não pode se repetir no meio for de mais de 1 caracter, a coisa fica um pouco mais complicada e feia de se escrever.

> Note que estou usando aqui apenas regex "pura", possível de ser representada por um autômato de estados finito; logo, retrovisores estão fora do meu escopo de escrita abaixo

Tome, por exemplo, a sequência `@€` como terminadora, e que eu preciso que ela não se repita. Assumindo que o iniciador `£` pode se repetir, e também na ausência de escapes.

Um simples `@` não significa que a sequência foi preenchida. Para tal, é necessário que o próximo caracter não seja `€`. E também pode ocorrer o caso de que o `@` seja a parte logo anterior ao terminador `@€`. Então eu preciso pegar, no miolo da regex:

- um `@` sucedido por qualquer coisa que não seja `€`
- o próprio `€` desde que garantido que não haja algum casamento com algo que termine em `@` no meio da repetição
- possivelmente uma fração do terminador

Posso separar o miolo na parte de passível repetição e na parte de incompletude. Assim, a parte de incompletude, para um terminador de 2 caracteres apenas, é `(@+)?` (já já explico a cruz de Kleene). E a parte passível de repetição?

```
([^@]|@+[^€])*
```

Assim, eu posso ter uma sequência arbitrária dentro dessa repetição que, garantidamente, não vai terminar com `@`. A repetição é composta de 2 grupos: `g1` que é qualquer coisa menos o primeiro caracter do terminador, e `g2`, que é o caracter iniciador seguido de necessariamente algo que quebre a sequência do terminador.

Então, para permitir também a parte inicial do terminador, permito que seu primeiro caracter se repita infinitamente, de modo opcional, após essa sequência, ficando assim toda a regex:

```
£([^@]|@+[^€])*(@+)?@€
```

E se o terminador fosse de 3 caracteres? Como o `@€¥`?

Bem, a ideia é semelhante, mas vai precisar negar no primeiro caracter, no segundo caracter e no terceiro caracter a sequência. Como fazemos isso?

- a negação do primeiro caracter é direta: `[^@]`
- a negação do segundo caracter em diante deve assumir a presença do primeiro caracter, com possibilidade de repetição, então vou colocá-las todas em um grupo precedido de `@*`
- a negação do segundo caracter (já considerando que foi tratada externamente a repetição do primeiro caracter), começa assumindo que seu casamento positivo para o primeiro caracter e negando o segundo caracter: `@[^€]`
- a negação do terceiro caracter (também assumindo que já foi tratada a repetição do primeiro caracter) precisa assumir que deram certo os dois primeiros caracteres: `@€[^¥]`

Então, fica assim a parte passível de repetição:

```
([^@]|@*(@[^€]|@€[^¥]))*
```

Para a parte de sequência incompleta, só tirar as listas negadas e a estrela de Kleene final, substituindo-a pela possibilidade de presença. Vou denotar como `''` a string de comprimento 0 apenas por uma questão de visualização, em seguida eliminando-a:

```
(''|@*(@''|@€''))?
```

Como não faz sentido algo concatenado da string vazia na regex desejada:

```
(''|@*(@|@€))?
```

Como não faz sentido a opção entre nada ou outra coisa, sempre recaindo sobre a outra coisa:

```
(@*(@|@€))?
```

Poderia seguir aqui apenas com isso, mas, se você prestar atenção, isso pode ser substituído por algo mais expressivo:

```
(@*(@(€)?)?)?
```

Onde cada parêntese após a repetição do primeiro caracter da sequência terminadora indica que é opcional aquela subsequência. Note, também, que só faria sentido dar casamento nesse grupo se e somente se tiver pelo menos uma parte da sequência, e que necessariamente deve ser o primeiro caracter. Portanto, isso poderia ser reescrito assim:

```
(@+(€)?)?
```

Tirando parênteses redundantes:

```
(@+€?)?
```

> Note, porém, que esse mesmo algoritmo poderia ser usado para uma string arbitrária `abcdefX`:
>
> ```
> (a+(b(c(d(ef?)?)?)?)?)?
> ```
>
> Essa expressão casa com qualquer subsequência do início de `abcdefX`

E como ficaria toda a expressão?

```
£([^@]|@*(@[^€]|@€[^¥]))*(@+€?)?@€¥
```

Dá para expandir essa lógica para mais caracteres, mas devo assumir que é bem trabalhoso e o tamanho aumenta exponencialmente. Também não levei em consequência a possibilidade de haver caracteres repetidos na sequência terminadora, isso pode eventualmente gerar um caso complexo que não foi devidamente tratado.

Comment: Muito bom (já votei ontem, mas só vim comentar agora)! Sobre o `£([^#£@]|#.)*@`, acho que vale mencionar que nesses casos é possível aplicar o ["unroll the loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018490). Compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/kbBKS5/1/debugger) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/G5th3f/1/debugger) a diferença na quantidade de passos de cada uma

Comment: Não conheço esse "unroll the loop", vou estudar sobre o assunto e assim que puder atualizo

Comment: excelente explicação, o desenvolvimento do pensamento até a resposta ajuda a esclarecer o resultado final

Comment: @hkotsubo, tem alguma questão aqui no SOpt sobre o _unroll the loop_? Tô começando a entender a técnica aqui, mas devo admitir que meus estudos estão bem desfocados

Comment: Fazendo uma [busca rápida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=unroll+the+loop) não encontrei. Talvez tenha com algum outro nome ou com termos relacionados (como "desempenho da regex", "regex lenta", etc), mas não cheguei a pesquisar tão a fundo...

Comment: @hkotsubo, achei uma resposta sua que menciona _unroll_, haha: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383091/64969

Comment: Sim, é a única referência que encontrei... :-) Eu lembro de ter visto perguntas antigas sobre o desempenho de regex, mas acho que não eram específicas sobre esta técnica, e sim mais genéricas. Talvez não tenha uma pergunta só sobre isso mesmo...

Comment: Aliás, nessa resposta que vc achou eu menciono [o livro](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0596528124/) que explica a técnica em detalhes. A leitura é densa (já reli algumas vezes e ainda não entendo 100%), mas muito interessante :-)

Answer (score 6):

Apenas complementando as outras respostas, a melhor opção para o seu caso específico seria de fato a primeira regex da [resposta do @Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400449/112052):

```
ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO[^%]*%
```

Ela usa uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^%]`, que significa "qualquer coisa que **não** seja o `%`".
**Só tem um detalhe**, se o texto tiver algo como:

```
ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO%
```

A regex também encontrará um *match*, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/n99EvJ/5/). Isso acontece porque o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, pode não ter nada entre "ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO" e o `%`.

Para forçar que tenha pelo menos um caractere entre o texto "ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO" e o `%`, basta trocar o `*` por `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências), [veja a diferença](https://regex101.com/r/n99EvJ/6/). Você ainda pode usar quantificadores customizados, com quantidades bem definidas. Por exemplo:

- `[^%]{5,20}`: deve ter no mínimo 5 e no máximo 20 caracteres que não sejam `%`
- `[^%]{20}`: deve ter exatamente 20 caracteres que não sejam `%`
- `[^%]{5,}`: deve ter no mínimo 5 caracteres que não sejam `%` (sem limite máximo)

Ajuste o quantificador de acordo com suas necessidades. Claro que, se você sabe que casos como `ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO%` não ocorrem no seu texto, tanto faz usar um ou outro, mas se quiser ser mais específico para evitar falsos positivos, basta escolher a opção mais adequada.

---

Se o formato da linha sempre segue o padrão indicado no texto (com essa mesma quantidade de colunas com números, por exemplo), você pode ser ainda mais específico:

```
ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO kWh \d+( \d+,\d+){4}%
```

Agora eu adicionei `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos), e `( \d+,\d+){4}` (espaço, dígitos, vírgula, dígitos, repetido 4 vezes), assim a regex só encontra o que estiver nesse formato específico. Se o formato varia, aí seria o caso de ajustar para pegar todas as variações.

Aqui você deve decidir se a regex vai validar o formato das informações, ou se vai só pegar "qualquer coisa", até encontrar o primeiro `%`. É sempre um *trade-off*: uma regex mais complexa pode validar o formato e as informações, mas ela fica mais difícil de manter e entender. Uma regex mais simples encontra o que for preciso, com a possibilidade de trazer coisas a mais (que precisariam ser validadas posteriormente, fora da regex).

Comment: Nem passou na minha cabeça a possibilidade do miolo vazio não ser válido. Obrigado pela observação

Comment: o grupo de captura com a negação do caractere "%" é genial, excelente resposta.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não foi mencionado na pergunta, então é perdoável esse esquecimento :-)

Comment: @Paz Créditos ao Jefferson, que colocou essa opção primeiro na resposta dele :-)

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do usuário [nullptbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/133853/nullptr) está quase correta, porém ela vai capturar da primeira ocorrência de `ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO`até a última ocorrência do caractere `%`. 
Então caso haja mais de uma ocorrência de porcentagem e o arquivo não esteja separado por quebras de linhas, haverão capturas indesejadas.

**Eu recomendo usar essa regex:** `(ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO(.|\n)*?%)`

---

- Funcionamento:

Ela irá capturar dês de a primeira ocorrência da sequencia `ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO` até a próxima ocorrência de `%` podendo ter caracteres e quebras de linhas entre os essas ocorrências.

[Você pode verificar o funcionamento dessa regex aqui](https://regex101.com/r/wF6JHp/1)

Answer (score 1):

Simples assim: `ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO.*%`

---

**EDIT**

Removendo o `%`: `ENERGIA ELETRICA CONSUMO.*(?=%)`

A exclusão dos delimitadores podem ser alcançados através de [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Veja funcionando [aqui](http://regexr.com/4iagt)

Comment: Quase perfeito! Preciso que ele vá somente até o primeiro %. É possível? De qq forma, já me ajudou muito!

Comment: @milho o senhor está se aproveitando de minha boa vontade -.- ainda bem que vontade eu tenho de sobra :D

Comment: O lookahead não elimina o problema de pegar coisas a mais caso tenha mais de um `%`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/n99EvJ/2/) (além do `%` não fazer parte do *match*). No caso, uma solução seria usar `.*?`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/n99EvJ/1/). Sem contar que o lookahead é mais ineficiente, compare a quantidade de passos [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/n99EvJ/3/debugger), [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/3jLsrR/3/debugger) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/n99EvJ/4/debugger). Claro que para strings pequenas não faz tanta diferença, mas de qq forma não acho necessário usá-lo nesse caso.